# Android notification-setStyle or bigText function not working

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

**setStyle** or **bigText** function not working. Actually i want to create bigpicture notification like flipkart amazon or other shopping sites. but it is not working so i just tried to check working of **setStyle** with simple code but it is also not working.

**NOTE:** I have not done any configration in xml(inside res)files.. please let me know if there is any requirment for some extra configration or requirments. i just created **MainActivity.java** file and written below code for notification.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                notificationinfo();
            }
        });
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

    }
    public void notificationinfo()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("test")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("body"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working as in your notification is not posted or something else?

Comment: it is being posted..but only title is appearing bigText contains are not appearing..same thing is happening with bigPictute function

Comment: Did you actually expand the notification? Only the topmost notification is auto-expanded - you need to two finger swipe down on any other notification to expand them.

Comment: I have done every thing...if u can give me your email id I can send you screenshot..

Comment: Here`s what I tested: 1. Huawei CHC-U01 running Android 4.4 -> big text NOT showing, cant expand
2. Samsung S5 Mini Android 6 -> NOT showing, but can expand
3. Samsung S4 Android 5.0 -> NOT showing, but can expand
4. Nexus 5x Android 8.1 -> showing
5. LG g6 Android 8.0 -> showing
6. Samsung S7 mit Android 8.0 -> NOT showing, but can expand

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I am in time. But I know that if you don't add simple text to your notificaton (setContentText(text)) in this way you will not see anything, excluding your title. I understand what you want. But you need drag down your notification message. But I am not sure that this feature will work in all android versions.

And, last little trick that can be very helpful for you! You can add a priority to your **notificationBuilder**. Just do **setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)**. It helps me. In this way your message will be expanded always and big text will be shown. Hope it will help you.